# My pets are always indoors, do they still need treatment for fleas and ticks?

Tags: cats, health, fleas, ticks

I have several cats that never go outside. Only time I take them outdoors is for vet visits.

Is it still necessary for flea and tick treatment?

Comment: Pets even if they live indoors need to be treated for fleas or ticks especially if you are not the first owner of your home. Fleas and ticks can survive even in the harshest climatic conditions so it could be possible that they are already in your home long before you were even there.

Answer (score 1):

That's a judgement call. They may be indoor-only critters, but you aren't, and your guests aren't, and it's not impossible for fleas or ticks to be carried indoors on you or your clothing... just as a mosquito carrying a disease might get through an open door or your screens.

On the other hand, some of the treatments may put some minor stress on the cats' systems. So it's a matter of trading off a known minor risk against a low probability but possibly more serious risk. It's also a matter of how willing you are to deal with the problem should it arise.

Recommendation: Ask your vet. They should know what the local risks are and be able to trade them off against benefits. My vet, in my part of the world, recommends a yearly heartworm treatment but doesn't think my indoor cats need flea/tick collars or drops. Your vet may have other recommendations based on their understanding of local conditions and the latest studies.

(My cats have been supervising as I type this message, and seem to approve.)